# Determining if a string can be permuted to a palindrome

Tags: c++, performance, palindrome

I am going through Elements of Programming Interview by Aziz, Lee and Prakash one of the questions is how to determine if a string can be permuted to a palindrome. For example `edified` can be permuted to `deified` and now its a palindrome.

So my first implementation is this:

```
bool CanFormPalindrome(const string& s) {
    std::unordered_map<char, int> letter_count;
    for(char c : s) {
      letter_count[c]++;
    }

    int odd_letter_count = 0;
    for(std::pair<char, int> letter : letter_count) {
      if(letter.second%2 != 0) {
        odd_letter_count++;
      }
    }

    return odd_letter_count <= 1;
}
```

After I passed all the tests I saw the book's cleaner and sleeker implementation (compared to my implementation) which is:

> ```
> bool CanFormPalindrome(const string& s) {
>   std::unordered_set<char> char_counter;
>   for(char c : s) {
>     if(char_counter.count(c)) {
>       char_counter.erase(c);
>     }
>     else {
>       char_counter.insert(c);
>     }
>   }
>   return char_counter.size() <= 1;
> }
> ```

When I saw the time difference the tester timed my test at around 30 ms and the book's implementation at around 100 ms. I am wondering why my implementation is faster than the book's. My suspicion is that the calls to `unordered_set`'s `count`, `erase`, and `insert` probably is the main bottle neck as opposed to just insert it just once and increment the value if it exists.

Another question is if you were to ask this on an interview would you care about the space time complexity over speed? Obviously the unordered_set is far more space efficient than the unordered_map, but if its for greater performance gain can we take up more space?

Comment: It would be great if you would provide the benchmarking code, and some data about the benchmarking process so we could compare with own versions.

Comment: As a side note you can stop your final check loop as soon as odd_letter_count reaches two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I much prefer your solution. It's easy to read and straightforward. The difference in size between the 2 is probably not that much. Their code has an `unordered_set` with a few elements in it. Your code has an `unordered_map` with likely 26 elements in it. We're talking about 26 * 5 = 130 bytes vs. say 5 or 10 bytes for the set on average. On modern systems, this is not a difference in memory usage. It's all below 1KB. If you're working with some old or oddball hardware and that becomes an issue, you can deal with it then.

However, if I were to see this code in production, I would probably want the following changes:

1. I would opt for using `auto` instead of the long type name in this line:

```
for(std::pair<char, int> letter : letter_count) {
```

I'd make it:

```
for(const auto& letter : letter_count) {
```

As mentioned in the discussion in the comments, making it a reference saves a copy of the `pair` and making it `const` lets a reader know that you aren't going to be modifying it.

2. I'd use more space between operators in the next line:

```
if(letter.second%2 != 0) {
```

would become:

```
if (letter.second % 2 != 0) {
```

It's just easier to read.

3. I might make that conditional into a named function just to make it clearer:

```
bool isOdd(const int x)
{
    return (x % 2) != 0
}

// ...
if  (isOdd(letter.second)) {
```

Comment: Bear in mind that `auto` copies the pair. An `auto&` may be more appropriate.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably better. Actually, even better would be `const auto&` since we aren't modifying the value. I'll update my answer.

Comment: `letter_count[c]++`: you might add that pre-increment is better when you don't need the intermediate value

Comment: The original post author should also have improved the second part of his algorithm: it isn't necessary to count all letters whose count is odd; he could break out as soon as 2 odd-count letters are detected. And `+1` if he uses `std::find_if` for this.

Comment: thanks for your input. i appreciate the feedback and yes i should definitely make it more legible!

Answer (score 3):

Updating an element in a collection is significantly faster than inserting or removing an element, as you've observed.  I think your code is better than the book's version.

We can be even more efficient by using a `std::array` if we convert characters to `unsigned char` for the indexing - then there's no insertion of elements required.  The flip side is that we check all possible characters, even those that never appear in the string; I'm guessing that's a small cost compared to allocating memory.

---

One improvement I'd recommend is to note that counts can't be negative:

```
std::unordered_map<char, unsigned int> letter_count;
```

(That also deals nicely with overflow, which is defined for unsigned types, and consistent with what we need).

---

Alternatively, you might simply toggle the value using XOR, rather than counting:

```
for (char c: s) {
  letter_count[c] ^= 1;
}
```

Then we only have to compare equality when looking for odd counts.

Using only one bit per possible character would allow us to use `std::bitset` as an alternative to `std::array`.  That trades some speed for lower storage requirement.

---

A slight improvement - we know the original string's length - if it's even, then there should be *no* odd counts at all, so we can exit the checking loop earlier.

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

bool CanFormPalindrome(const std::string& s) {
    std::unordered_map<char, bool> letter_count;
    for (char c: s) {
      letter_count[c] ^= 1;
    }

    int odd_letter_count = s.length() % 1;
    for (const auto& letter: letter_count) {
        if ((odd_letter_count -= letter.second) < 0) {
            return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
}
```

---

Here's a version using `std::array`, and a standard algorithm instead of a loop:

```
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <climits>

bool CanFormPalindrome(const std::string& s) {
    std::array<bool, UCHAR_MAX> letter_count = {};
    for (unsigned char c: s) {
        letter_count[c] ^= 1;
    }

    int odd = s.length() % 2;
    return std::none_of(letter_count.begin(), letter_count.end(),
                        [&odd](auto x) { return (odd -= x) < 0; });
}
```

The `std::none_of()` function returns early in the same way as the loop above.  Also (though unlikely to be helpful here), from C++17 onwards it has an option to parallelize its execution.

---

And some tests (for all versions of the code):

```
int main()
{
    return
        + !CanFormPalindrome("")
        + !CanFormPalindrome("a")
        +  CanFormPalindrome("ab")
        +  CanFormPalindrome("abcb")
        + !CanFormPalindrome("abab")
        + !CanFormPalindrome("edified")
        ;
}
```

Comment: May be you could do counting of `true` elements and then comparing that with length being odd or not? Because then it would be kind of correspondence relationship. `std::none_of` is somewhat peculiar at the moment. Also, why not `std::bitset`?

Comment: Ah, I was going to mention bitset (trading speed for size) but forgot.  I'll edit that in.  Yes, you could go back to counting (arguably clearer, but you lose the early exit from the loop for the failure cases).  What's peculiar about `none_of`?  Is the fact that I capture by reference, or something else?

Comment: `std::none_of` is really expressive here, and optimal since you return as soon as `odd -= x` is negative.

Comment: @TobySpeight, I forgot about early return, sorry.

Comment: The only thing that might improve your code is to count the number of odd letter-counts while you're filling `letter_count`, and then compare it to `s.length() % 2`. For example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/4ADDXjaYI1NefIdJ

Comment: @papagaga: Good thinking - I like that one!  In fact you can assign and test together (but warn the reader!), e.g. `if ((letter_count[c] ^= true)) ++odd; else --odd;`  (Have I spent too much time on Code Golf lately?)

Comment: If we [can] restrict to `a-z`, how about: `unsigned int letter_count = 0; for (unsigned char c : s) letter_count ^= 1u << (c - (unsigned) 'a'); unsigned int two_odd = 0; two_odd += (letter_count != 0); letter_count &= letter_count - 1; two_odd += (letter_count != 0);` Otherwise, we could generalize to `unsigned long long letter_count[4]` [or `std::array<unsigned long long,4>`] and  xor the equivalent bit mask. Then, loop through the array with the `x &= x - 1` trick, stopping early if the count hits 2.

Comment: @Craig, Arithmetic with printable characters is fragile - you can't assume that `a`..`z` have consecutive encodings, for instance.  And `unsigned int` isn't necessarily more than 16 bits.  If you're tight for space, then `std::bitset` is a much safer alternative.